# Dagger 2 Dispatching Android Injector

Tags: android, dagger

I am trying to use the new dagger api for activity injection but I am getting error `lateinit property dispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized`

```
// AppComponent.kt
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivitiesModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: Application)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun build(): AppComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun bindApplication(application: Application): Builder
    }
}
```

Activity Modules file

```
@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun provideRestaurantMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

In my MainActivity I am calling the injection

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

And in my Application

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector{

@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = dispatchingAndroidInjector

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .bindApplication(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
}

}
```

Is there anything else I am missing in the hooking of the modules and components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "fun inject(app: Application)" should be

fun inject(app: App)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong version of `AndroidInjection` and `AndroidSupportInjectionModule`.

Try to replace
`AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class` with `AndroidInjectionModule::class`.